# Flex Spark Combobox displaying icon into the main combobox area?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I wish to display icon into the spark combobox main area.
I can display icons inside the elements list, but the icon doesnt appear into the main area.

- How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always add your own skin to add an icon depending on the currently selected item in your list.

Comment: ye, but this is long and not checked road to be walked, i were searching if there is something prechecked and tested already.

Comment: this is not long. Would take about 5 minutes and 1 line of added code to the skin.

Comment: Jax is right, if you're using FB 4.5 you simply go to the design mode and in the skin dropdown of the ComboBox and hit "create skin". Then add your Icon next to the Combo inputbox and you're done. It's that easy.

Comment: y, i did it before ask the question. :| but the result were some anoing space which is unclicable and overall  ugly

Comment: any ideas or i shall close the question ?

Comment: Done. Skining is the way to be followed in Flex. Thanks :)